# Spring, Hibernate :java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test2.ciudad_persona' doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Does anyone know why is this? I get that error, when i do a GET request to my Spring Boot Backend, It seems to be searching for a table which doesn't exists, i think it is the @OneToMany in Ciudad and TipoDocumento class but i dont know why this is happening, i saw this in different tutorials but i am trying Spring boot for firts time

```
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4418) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4408) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1187) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:1006) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        at com.sinfloo.crud.Ciudad$HibernateProxy$CJmUAjFi.getNombre(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1512) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:335) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test2.ciudad_persona' doesn't exist
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
        ... 85 common frames omitted
```

but focusing in this:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test2.ciudad_persona' doesn't exist'
```

i don't even have that table in my database.
This are all of my documents:

Persona.java:

```
    package com.sinfloo.crud;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "persona")
    public class Persona {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "idpersona")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;
     @Column(name = "nombres")
     private String name;
     @Column(name = "apellidos") 
     private String apellido;
     @Column(name = "documento") 
     private String documento;
     @Column(name = "email") 
     private String email;
     @Column(name = "fechanacimiento") 
     private String fec_nac;
     @Column(name = "telefono") 
     private String tel;
     @Column(name = "password") 
     private String pass;
     @Column(name = "usuario") 
     private String user;
     
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idtipodocumento",referencedColumnName = "idtipodocumento")
    private TipoDocumento tp;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idciudad",referencedColumnName = "idciudad")
    private Ciudad ciudad;
    
           public int getId() {
                return id;
            }
        
            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
        
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
        
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
        
            public String getApellido() {
                return apellido;
            }
        
            public void setApellido(String apellido) {
                this.apellido = apellido;
            }
        
            public String getDocumento() {
                return documento;
            }
        
            public void setDocumento(String documento) {
                this.documento = documento;
            }
        
            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }
        
            public void setEmail(String email) {
                this.email = email;
            }
        
            public String getFec_nac() {
                return fec_nac;
            }
        
            public void setFec_nac(String fec_nac) {
                this.fec_nac = fec_nac;
            }
        
            public String getTel() {
                return tel;
            }
        
            public void setTel(String tel) {
                this.tel = tel;
            }
        
            public String getPass() {
                return pass;
            }
        
            public void setPass(String pass) {
                this.pass = pass;
            }
        
            public String getUser() {
                return user;
            }
        
            public void setUser(String user) {
                this.user = user;
            }
        
            public TipoDocumento getPersonas() {
                return tp;
            }
        
            public void setPersonas(TipoDocumento tp) {
                this.tp = tp;
            }
        
            public Ciudad getCiudad() {
                return ciudad;
            }
        
            public void setCiudad(Ciudad ciudad) {
                this.ciudad = ciudad;
            }
         
    
     
    }
```

TipoDocumento.Java:

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

    package com.sinfloo.crud;
    
    
    
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    /**
     *
     * @author Nico&Sebas
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tipodocumento")
    public class TipoDocumento {
        @Id
        @Column(name ="idtipodocumento")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @Column(name = "nombre")
        private String nombre;
        @Column(name = "descripcion")
        private String descripcion;
        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Persona> persona;
        
        
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
    
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
    
        public String getDescripcion() {
            return descripcion;
        }
    
        public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
            this.descripcion = descripcion;
        }
    
        public List<Persona> getPersona() {
            return persona;
        }
    
        public void setPersona(List<Persona> persona) {
            this.persona = persona;
        }
        
    }
```

Ciudad.Java:

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.sinfloo.crud;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    /**
     *
     * @author Nico&Sebas
     */
    
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "ciudad_persona")
        public class Ciudad{
        @Id
        @Column(name = "idciudad")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @Column(name = "nombre")
        private String nombre;
        @Column(name = "descripcion")
        private String descripcion;
        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Persona> persona;
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
    
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
    
        public String getDescripcion() {
            return descripcion;
        }
    
        public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
            this.descripcion = descripcion;
        }
    
        public List<Persona> getPersona() {
            return persona;
        }
    
        public void setPersona(List<Persona> persona) {
            this.persona = persona;
        }
        
    }
```

Controlador.Java(Controller):

```
    package com.sinfloo.crud;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
    @RestController
    
    @RequestMapping({"/personas"})
    public class Controlador {
       @Autowired
       PersonaService service;
       
       @GetMapping
       public List<Persona> listar(){
           return service.list();
       }
       
       @PostMapping
       public Persona agregar(@RequestBody Persona persona){
           return service.add(persona);
       }
       @GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
       public Persona listarId(@PathVariable("id")int id){
           return service.listarId(id);
        }
       
       @PutMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
       public Persona editar(@RequestBody Persona persona,@PathVariable("id")int id){
       persona.setId(id);
       return service.editar(persona);
       }
       
       @DeleteMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
       public Persona delete(@PathVariable("id")int id){
       return service.delete(id);
       }
       
    }
```

I am new in Spring and im trying to do a simple CRUD

Comment: @Entity@Table on a class defines it as a db table. So it should be present in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear, it verifies that the table exists with that name and that the schema is correct. If it is not, try to write down the entity like this:

```
@Table (name = "ciudad_persona", schema = "your_schema")
```